# Python: from list to enumerated list to pass to lambda reduce function

Tags: python, list, enumeration

I am trying to pass a list of hex char, into a lambda function, reduce to calculate a total decimal value. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but the python interpreter wouldn't recognize list(enumerate(reversed(numList)) as a list of tuples.

```
  numList =  ['3', '0', 'e', 'f', 'e', '1']
  reduce(lambda sum,(up,x):sum+ int(x,16)*16**up,
         enumerate(reversed(numList)))
```

when I print out

```
  list(enumerate(reversed(numList))
```

It is a list of tuples.

```
  [(0, '1'), (1, 'e'), (2, 'f'), (3, 'e'), (4, '0'), (5, '3')]
```

But it spit our error:  can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple

UPDATE:

The code is now working with a minor addition   ",0" added to the lambda

```
    reduce(lambda sum,(up,x):sum+ int(x,16)*16**up,
         list(enumerate(reversed(numList))),0)
```

I don't understand what that means. Also I am not sure what is the best way to approach this.

> that means you make sure, that it starts with 0 instead of the first Argument - in this case (0,'1') - because otherwise the types dont match? – am2 1 min ago

.

> the third argument you add is initializer. without it, the sum in first iteration will be (0,'1'). so you were trying to evaluate (0,'1')+int(x,16)*16**up which is invalid. – ymonad 14 mins ago

UPDATE 2:

```
reduce(lambda sum,(up,x):sum+ int(x,16)*16**up,enumerate(reversed(numList)),0)
```

is just as good and `enumerate()` returns iter and `list(enumerate...)` is redundant.

**Marked it as solved.**

Comment: the third argument you add is initializer. without it, the `sum` in first iteration will be `(0,'1')`. so you were trying to evaluate `(0,'1')+int(x,16)*16**up` which is invalid. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce

Comment: ah ok. the message is saying that I am trying to add the int into the tuple. (I was thinking the other way around.) I got it now, thanks.

Comment: that means you make sure, that it starts with 0 instead of the first Argument - in this case (0,'1') - because otherwise the types dont match?

Comment: One quick question, is this `enumerate(list)` a proper way to extract the index of a list when using lambda functions? What are the other options I have?

Comment: I have added Pham's answer you intended to mark as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the generic `reduce` function when all you really need is to calculate the sum.

This works and is vastly simpler:

```
sum( int(x,16)*16**up for up,x in enumerate(reversed(numList)) )
```

---

Also, I'm going to guess you already know you can do the exact same thing like this:

```
int(''.join(numList), 16)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was actually exploring how to use lambda function properly. If no other better answer, I will accept this as final answer.